# How to assert_called_with the first call if the method has been called twice in another method?

Tags: python, magicmock

eg in t.py

```
def a(obj):
  print obj

def b():
  a(1)
  a(2)
```

then:

```
from t import b

with patch('t.a') as m:
  b()
  m.assert_called_with(1)
```

I get:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: a(1)
Actual call: a(2)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most straightforward approach would be to get the first item from [`mock.call_args_list`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.call_args_list) and check if it is called with `1`:

> call_args_list
>
> This is a list of all the calls made to the mock object in sequence
>   (so the length of the list is the number of times it has been called).

```
assert m.call_args_list[0] == call(1)
```

where `call` is imported from `mock`: `from mock import call`.

Also, [`mock_calls`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.mock_calls) would work in place of `call_args_list` too.

Another option would be to use [`assert_any_call()`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.assert_any_call):

```
m.assert_any_call(1)
```